# Neural Network with inputs of different sizes

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, neural-network, tensorflow2.0

I would like to use a neural network in Keras that takes 2 inputs of different sizes (a vector `v` and a matrix `A`) and outputs a vector `u`, which is `v` after acted upon by `A`.
I have managed to input the matrix and vector. The problem is, when I try to use the vector `u` as the target when fitting the model, it complains:

```
ValueError: Data cardinality is ambiguous: 
x sizes: 70, 312 
y sizes: 70
Make sure all arrays contain the same number of samples.
```

Comment: You can make train and test sets using [scikit-learn's `train_test_split()`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html). If you want to work with inputs of different types/sizes, [you'll need to use the Functional API and make a complex topological model](https://keras.io/guides/functional_api/).

Comment: Could you please share how you are defining the model to understand the issue or minimal reproducible code to replicate the error?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the example code. I think it can help you.

```
input_layer = Input(shape=(None, None, channels))
  x = Conv2D(16,(4,4), activation = 'relu')(input_layer) 
  x = Conv2D(32,(4,4), activation = 'relu')(x)        
  x = Dropout(0.2)(x)
  x = Conv2D(64,(4,4), activation = 'relu')(x)      
  x = Dropout(0.5)(x)
  x = Conv2D(128, (1,1))(x)                         
  x = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)                  
  output_layer = Dense(5, activation = "softmax")(x)
  model = Model(inputs = input_layer, outputs=output_layer)
  model.compile(optimizer = "adam", loss = "categorical_crossentropy",
                metrics=["accuracy"])
```

Comment: Where are you using mixed inputs (i.e. a matrix and a vector) here?

Comment: Thank you. I've googled many times how to define a neural network for varying sized images and I never came across any mention of setting the input size to (None, None, channels). I had no idea you could do that. This solved my issue. Why doesn't anyone talk about this!?!?!

Answer (score 0):

The best option in your case zero padding or padding up would likely be the best decision in your situation. Inputs are only zeroed out in these situations to account for the absence of data. It is frequently used for CNN pictures' borders.

An RNN, which is a simpler option and can easily accommodate your variable-length inputs, is another option.